# Photoshop: how to mask blurred background

Tags: photoshop, masks

I have a portrait with a blurred background. I'd like to use this to create a mask or for alpha channel or to erase the background.

So after editing I want to have an image with perfect white or transparency where was the background and keep the face unchanged.

Is it possible?

What I tried yet:

- made the image copy
- converted this copy B/W
- made the copy of this B/W layer
- blured this copy
- subtracted these copies:

[image]

So I hoped that *blurred blur* will be almost the same as *blur* and *blurred sharp* will differ from *sharp* parts of the picture. And the difference will be as an indication of the blureness. But I see that my idea did not worked for some reasons.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the background of a photo using GIMP?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/how-can-i-remove-the-background-of-a-photo-using-gimp)

Comment: Hi, [edit] your question to show us what the original photo looks like to best guide you on how to remove the background.

Answer (score 1):

A little confused about your question: are you attempting to keep the face and remove the existing background? Are you having difficulty making a decent selection?

If the above is correct, you'll want to make a selection of the face.There are a multitude of ways to do that in Photoshop. In this case,you'll want to make a selection of the background. If the background is solid, you could use color range. Otherwise you could make a selection of the face and then use inverse.

I have found the select and mask option invaluable in refining my selections so that I don't have a halo or that pesky little color around the edges. There is a definite learning curve but well worth it.

Once you have made the selection  hit "delete" on your keyboard and there you have it! You can then make a new document and do what you want with that background - make it white or transparent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the best way would be to learn:

1. How to use masks
2. Make and enhance selections in Photoshop

This is **THE** major first step when learning how to edit an image, beyond the classic and global adjustments, such as contrast, luminosity, curves or B&W conversion.

Concerning your image, **Photoshop may have a *magic* tool to help you**:

> Select > Focus Area

It *automatically* select the image areas in focus and can create a selection from it. It is not perfect, but if your background is blurry enough it might do what you want in a single step.

Tutorial on adobe.com: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/select-area-focus.html

Comment: When did they add this?

Comment: Since the CC 2014 version apparently